# Reduce FLV file size

Tags: video, flash, compression, flv

I have successfully converted an AVI file to FLV, but it's too large a file. How can I reduce it's file size without editing out any portions of its content?

Comment: How did you convert it? If you provide the command, maybe we can help you tweak it to reduce the size.

Comment: To agree with @scmpt.com, also state your operationg system and what you mean by "too large". Are you willing to reduce quality to reduce size?

Comment: Maybe it has just the right size, yeah. We would like to know what you specify as "too large". Length of video, etc?

Comment: Sorry all, I asked this one behalf of a friend so I don't have details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [eRightSoft SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) (free solution) and reduce screen size (you can try other options also).

Comment: I'm selecting this one because it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Use Adobe media encoder, which you could have options for reducing size.